# How to create a Class instance with all the parameters from the original Class accessible?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's take for example a class from a package.
With this package comes the class FlushBar(), and when you want to create a custom instance you have all sorts of parameters:

```
Flushbar errorFlushBar = Flushbar(
    title: "Deleted",
    
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.easeOutCirc,
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFF2727),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(
      6.0,
    ),
    borderRadius: SmoothBorderRadius(
      cornerRadius: 12,
      cornerSmoothing: 0.7,
    ),
  );
```

and then when you want to use it in the widget tree you can call some methods:

```
errorFlushBar.show()
```

But what if wanted to define a custom Flusbar() instance, that is still customizable by calling the default parameters?
If a define a custom Flusher() instance like this, then I am stuck with the parameters I defined:

```
MyCustomFLushBarsClass {
 
 FlushBar myFlushBar = Flushbar(
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.easeOutCirc,
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFF2727),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(
      6.0,
    ),
    borderRadius: SmoothBorderRadius(
      cornerRadius: 12,
      cornerSmoothing: 0.7,
    ),
  );
}
```

What I imagine is something like this:

```
//in some widget..
myFlushBar(title: "Some String", color: Colors.white,).show()
```

Comment: this seems like you ca, achieve it with a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a function that takes the parameters and return the instance:

```
    class FlushBars {

  Flushbar createFlushBar(
    String message,
    Color color,
    IconData iconData,
    bool hasButton, [
    String buttonText,
    Function onP,
  ]) {
    return Flushbar(
      message: message,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.easeOutCirc,
      backgroundColor: color,
      shouldIconPulse: true,
      // titleSize: 12.0,
      messageSize: 14.0,
      mainButton: hasButton
          ? CupertinoButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(
                buttonText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: onP,
            )
          : null,
      endOffset: Offset(0, -0.15),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
        12.0,
      ),
      icon: Icon(
        iconData,
        size: 15.0,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(
        6.0,
      ),
      borderRadius: SmoothBorderRadius(
        cornerRadius: 12,
        cornerSmoothing: 0.7,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```